# SameSite attribute cannot be changed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session-cookies, .net-6.0, app-startup

- So it is not a "My PC" problem. I deployed the app on our test server and the changes still don't get applied. Next step is to dig deeper and see if some identity related configuration was overwritten somewhere.

---

I've set the `Cookie.SameSite` value to `SameSiteMode.Lax` inside`services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(...)`. Now I'm still getting the cookie with the SameSite value set to strict after I restarted the app and signed in.

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(...):

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "sessionCookie";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                options.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.LogoutPath = $"/SignOut";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Account/AccessDenied";
            });
```

- Tested in both Chrome and Firefox - same behaviour.
- Cookies were cleared and I also restarted everything.

  - Yes, also my PC.
- I can change any other attribute.

  - I've changed the name, secure and other attributes without fail.
- We are using IdenityServer4 with our own implementation of `IdentityUser`:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the following line of code which came way before the lines shown in the question:

`services.AddCookieConfiguration();`

This **was** an method with return type `IServiceCollection`, which was written by another developer a few months ago. Because of this "error" I realized how messy our `Startup.cs` actually is and extracted some configurations into their own methods.